# Blade returns "1" while trying to display Json Data

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am  trying to display the json results in the blade, but when I try to display the state name ,district name, from the corresponding relations, I am getting 1 in the Blade,
I am able to display the 'user' relation and 'newInstallation'.

> My Model

**NewInstallation.php**

```
public function newInstallationPrePayment()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NewInstallationPrePayment::class, 'installation_order_id', 'id');
}

public function state()
{
    return $this->hasOne(State::class, 'id', 'state');
}

public function district()
{
    return $this->hasOne(District::class, 'id', 'district');
}
```

**NewInstallationPaymentStatus.php**

```
public function newInstallationPrePayment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(NewInstallationPrePayment::class, 'order_name', 'order_name');
}
```

> Controller

```
$new_installation_order = NewInstallationPaymentStatus::with([
        'newInstallationPrePayment.newInstallation.state',
        'newInstallationPrePayment.newInstallation.district',
        'newInstallationPrePayment.newInstallation.user']
    )->findOrFail($id);
```

> Blade

```
{{$new_installation_order}}
```

I am getting below json result for the above

But when I try calling state

```
{{$new_installation_order['newInstallationPrePayment']['newInstallation']['district'] }}
```

*When I use this I am getting 1*

**Json:**

```
{
   "id":2,
   "user_id":1,
   "order_name":"ORDER_ID_NW_SW-24",
   "order_amount":"118.00",
   "referenceId":"290927",
   "txStatus":"SUCCESS",
   "paymentMode":"CREDIT_CARD",
   "txMsg":"Transaction Successful",
   "txTime":"2020-03-31 14:34:52",
   "order_status":"NEW",
   "deleted_at":null,
   "created_at":"2020-03-31T16:37:34.000000Z",
   "updated_at":"2020-03-31T16:37:34.000000Z",
   "new_installation_pre_payment":{
      "id":21,
      "user_id":0,
      "installation_order_id":24,
      "order_name":"ORDER_ID_NW_SW-24",
      "payment_status":"SUCCESS",
      "created_at":"2020-03-31T09:04:33.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-03-31T16:37:34.000000Z",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "new_installation":{
         "id":24,
         "f_name":"Full Name",
         "p_no":"",
         "address":"Address",
         "address_line_1":"Address",
         "state":{
            "id":1,
            "state_name":"Tamil Nadu",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-03-27T04:16:37.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-03-27T04:16:37.000000Z"
         },
         "district":{
            "id":1,
            "state_id":1,
            "district_name":"Chennai",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-03-27T04:17:22.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-03-27T04:17:22.000000Z"
         },
         "area":"Area Name",
         "landmark":"Land Mark",
         "pincode":"123456",
         "fees_id":1,
         "user_id":1,
         "deleted_at":null,
         "created_at":"2020-03-31T09:04:33.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2020-03-31T09:04:33.000000Z",
         "user":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"admin",
            "email":"tesmachino@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at":null,
            "created_at":"2020-03-29T10:33:36.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2020-03-29T10:33:36.000000Z"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Omar Jayed's answer should fix the problem. In the future, you can always use `php artisan tinker` to play with the results. You could analyze that model right inside tinker.

Comment: I realixed that Omay Jayed's answer won't make a difference. You can always use `php artisan tinker` to play with the results. It's pretty much a REPL; perfect for debugging. Can you try using it and seeing what value you get?

Answer (score 1):

I don't if you are encoding the data to json and then sending to the view. It seems to be a json object, not php array. That;s why blade can not iterate through it. If you are encoding it as json try not to do that. Or try to decode it before sending it to the view.

```
return view('viewname')->with(['new_installation_order' => json_decode($new_installation_order)])
```

Then try this

```
{{$new_installation_order->newInstallationPrePayment->newInstallation->district }}
```

You can also decode the json in blade file. Do whatever works best for you.

Comment: This won't make any difference. `$variable['key']` and `$variable->key` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Nahiyan. I seemed to miss that. Sorry about that. However, I edited my answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @omarjayed , Nahiyan -- I updated the state to State & district to District in Model relationship  and it started working..  I am wondering how !!

Comment: I bet your DB engine is case-sensitive. Try running some SQL queries with varying capitalization and letting us know? It may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try passing the specific parameter to your view instead of the entire object. I suspect it is because you are passing the json as a string to the view.

So try something like this instead:

```
$district = $new_installation_order['newInstallationPrePayment']['newInstallation']['district'];

return view('test')->with(['district' => $district]);
```

**Can you post the entire method that is being called on your controller, or at least the return statement?**

Comment: Thanks mchljams -- I updated the state to State & district to District in Model relationship .. its working